# Regex Break String Into Groups

Tags: regex

I have a string:

```
ABC/12345.DEF/ZYX.THIS IS THE REST OF THE STRING
```

I need regex that will break this into 3 names groups:

```
FIRST: 12345
SECOND: ZYX
THIRD: THIS IS THE REST OF THE STRING
```

This is what I have come up with:

```
(?=.*\bABC\/(?<FIRST>[\w\d\s,]*)\.\b)(?=.*\bDEF\/(?<SECOND>[\w])\b)(?<THIRD>[\w\W\s]*)
```

That yields:

```
FIRST: 12345
SECOND: ZYX
THIRD: ABC/12345.DEF/ZYX.THIS IS THE REST OF THE STRING
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `\bABC\/(?<FIRST>[^.\/]+)\.[^\/]*\/(?<SECOND>[^.]+)\.(?<THIRD>.*)`? See https://regex101.com/r/TH9TIc/1

Comment: You are using positive lookaheads `(?=` while you could match instead. Note that `\w` also matches `\d` and you could shorten the character class in the third group to  `[\w\W]*`

Comment: Did you use my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex uses positive lookaheads before it hits the third capture group - this (ironically) forces it to capture the first and second capture groups in the final, third capture group. Here is an example that doesn't use lookaheads.

`ABC\/(?<FIRST>[^\.\n]+)\.DEF\/(?<SECOND>[^\.\n]+)\.(?<THIRD>.*)`

- `ABC\/` Read `ABC/`
- `(?<FIRST>[^\.\n]+)` Named capture group that captures all characters not `.` or newline, up to first occurrence of either.
- `\.DEF\/` Read `.DEF/`
- `(?<SECOND>[^\.\n]+)` Same as first capture group.
- `\.` Read `.`
- `(?<THIRD>.*)` Capture everything else.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/54HXZM/3/)

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped!  I used suggestions here to get it the way I needed it.

Comment: @nmrandy We're all glad to help. Please consider adding an answer to your own question explaining what you did, and then accepting your own answer - this allows other users in the future to see what you did!